# Calling non-template base class constructor in class derived from templated intermediary

Tags: c++, templates, mfc, constructor, base-class

```
template <class WndClass>
class screenhelpers : public WndClass
{
public:
    typedef WndClass BaseClass;
    typedef typename screenhelpers<WndClass> ThisClass;
    CRect GetControlRect(CWnd *pControl) const
    {               
            CRect rectWindow(0,0,0,0);
            if (!pControl)
                    return rectWindow;
            pControl->GetWindowRect(&rectWindow);
            this->ScreenToClient(&rectWindow);
            return rectWindow;
    }
};

class MyDialog : public screenhelpers<CDialog>
{
public:
    typedef screenhelpers<CDialog>::BaseClass MDialog;
    MyDialog(int i);
    MyDialog(LPCSTR lpszTemplateName, CWnd *pParentWnd);
    MyDialog(int nIDTemplate, CWnd *pParentWnd);
};

MyDialog::MyDialog(int i)
{
    BaseClass b;    
}

MyDialog::MyDialog(LPCSTR lpszTemplateName, CWnd *pParentWnd)
:    MyDialog::BaseClass(lpszTemplateName, pParentWnd)
{    
}


MyDialog::MyDialog(int nIDTemplate, CWnd *pParentWnd)
    :       MyDialog::CDialog(nIDTemplate, pParentWnd)
{
}
```

I don't see why I cannot seem to call the base class of screenhelpers.

If MyDialog inherits from screenhelpers, and screenhelpers inherits from CDialog, why can't I call CDialog?

Comment: I've got another simplified example `class Bob
{
public:
       Bob() : t(12){}
    Bob(int i) : t(i){}
       int t;
};

template <class Base>
class Bill : public Base
{
public:
       Bill() : s(20){}
       typedef Base BaseClass;
       int s;
};

class it : public Bill<Bob>
{
public:
     it(int i) { s = i; t= 1;}  
     //Create equivalent of above line that explicitly intialises the t that resides in Bob

#if 1//My unworking attempt
  it (double d) : BaseClass(30) {}
#endif
};
`

Comment: The it constructor is modifying t which is a member of Bob, and so that proves that the base class Bob exists within it

Comment: It would help if you'd point out the errors you're getting, I had to guess in my answer.

Comment: Oohps.  When trying to use the typedef `error C2614: 'MyDialog' : illegal member initialization: 'BaseClass' is not a base or member`

Comment: and when trying to use CDialog `error C2614: 'MyDialog' : illegal member initialization: 'CDialog' is not a base or member`

Answer (score 3):

The initialization list in the constructor can only call its immediate parent's constructor, not one further up the chain. That's why you can't initialize CDialog directly.

Your screenhelpers class doesn't define a constructor that takes two parameters, so that's not going to work either. Even if you add such a constructor, I'm not sure it's valid syntax to refer to it by the typedefed name, you might need to use `screenhelpers<CDialog>` instead.

Comment: GCC 4.6.1 says: "error: ISO C++ forbids nested type ‘screenhelpers’ with same name as enclosing class [-fpermissive]" That said, a class typedef to the class's type itself doesn't really make sense, since you would already *have* the type of the class.

Comment: @Kerrek - A ThisClass typedef would be ok, but perhaps skipping the incorrect `typename` would make the compiler happier?

Comment: @Bo: It would, indeed! :-) So... (why) is this a useful idea?

Comment: @Kerrek could you explain a little more?

Comment: @Stone: I mean, why would you need a typedef to refer to a type which you already have? Suppose you say `typedef screenhelpers<CrazyClass> Foo;`. Now you have `Foo::ThisClass`, but why, it's the same as `Foo`! What's the situation where you'd need `ThisClass`?

Comment: @Kerrek: I don't think I do.  I was just trying to think of what other way I could get to specify the base class CDialog constructor in my class.

Comment: Does the notify thing need a colon?

Comment: @Kerrek - I don't think it is useful at all. :-) *Some* people believe it is easier to have names like `self` or `parent` inside each class. Let them believe that!

Comment: @Stone: Who notify what when?

Comment: @Stone, if you're talking about the `@` notify notation in the comments, I think it's pretty free form - any punctuation will do, even just a space.

Answer (score 1):

If `MyDialog` constructor were allowed to call `CDialog` constructor, the latter would be called twice: once by `MyDialog` and once by `screenhelpers`. That would be a disaster.

If you need to control how `CDialog` constructor is called from `MyDialog`, you need to use virtual inheritance:

```
template <class WndClass>
class screenhelpers : public virtual WndClass
```

Then you will **have** (not just be able) to call `CDialog` constructor from `MyDialog`.

Note that this may have other effects on your design.